# Python cannot import scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have Python 3.7.3 installed and installed numpy, scipy via pip (cmd -> python -m pip install --user numpy scipy) and am able to import numpy, scipy if I use an admin command prompt to import both numpy and scipy. However, if I don't use an admin cmd prompt, or try to import scipy from the Python shell, I receive traceback errors like the following:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Does this traceback error come from not installing scipy in a certain way? Thanks for the help in advance.

When doing checking pip and python versions in cmd, here's my output:

pip --version
pip 19.1 from c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

python --version
Python 3.7.3

Comment: Perhaps you have a pip/python version mismatch.  Edit the question to include the output of `pip --version` and `python --version`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the location of your python scripts to the Path in Environment Variables.

`C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

You mentioned that you've already installed the packages. And the packages are stored in the `site-packages` file inside `Python37` folder. So the error must be because you didn't add these to the path.

Comment: `import numpy` works, so I wouldn't think this is a path issue.